# How to connect to select/deselect event?

Tags: python

I want when a user is selecting/deselecting an object to do something.

I'm working on an alignment tool (free to use) and I manage to make almost everything work.

If you select several objects and click align x or rotate x, it will align rotation/scale/dimension/move

But I can't figure out how to hook into select/deselect event so that I can automatically align objects based on what is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to claim this is the correct way; but it will work

```
import bpy


@bpy.app.handlers.persistent
def _depsgraph_update(scene):
    print(bpy.context.selected_objects)


bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(_depsgraph_update)
# bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.remove(_depsgraph_update)
```

The other thing you can try; is listening for the active object changing - on the basis that you can't select without changing the active object.  Note you won't get a change notification on undo

```
bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
     key=(bpy.types.LayerObjects, "active"),
     owner=object(),
     args=tuple(),
     notify=callback,
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will go with the first approach

Comment: IMO not good practice to mix context and handlers.  The context scene isn't necessarily the one being handled by the handler. Look over  the scene objects collection.